# UICollectionview not fully loaded image from CoreData get randomly blank cell image

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Hi I currently have a trouble with UICollectionView on iOS 10 + Swift 3. Once my View loaded the ImageView in each cell get randomly blank some of them can be loaded.

[Here is my random output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6vad.png)

Now I've to give a delay before I reloadData of the CollectionView but it still not 100% resolve my problem sometime my cell still blank.

**ViewController**

```
@IBOutlet weak var petCollection: UICollectionView!
var petObj: [Pet] = []

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.petObj.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! PetCollectionViewCell

    let nsDocumentDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
    let nsUserDomainMask    = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
    let paths               = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true)

    let dirPath          = paths.first!
    let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent(petObj[indexPath.item].petImage!)
    let image    = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path)

    cell.collectionViewImage.image = image

    return cell
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.petCollection.delegate = self
    self.petCollection.dataSource = self
}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        petCollection.reloadData()
    }
}
```

**UICollectionViewCell**

```
class PetCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewImage: UIImageView!
}
```

My assumed is reloadData was called before UICollectionView finished create cell.

I used CoreData to store file path and all of image has been saved in document directory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your collection view will load its data when viewDidLoad gets called and that's when your user enters this view controller.

Instead of using delays to reload the data asynchronous you should use this library:

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

It will handle the asynchronous loading of your images.

You can use the library like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! PetCollectionViewCell

    let nsDocumentDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
    let nsUserDomainMask    = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
    let paths               = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true)


    cell.collectionViewImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "yourPathToImage"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Can that library use with local image file? Because I used CoreData to store image path that saved in the document directory.

Comment: Yes you can use local images too. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37970124/storing-and-retrieving-images-from-documents-directory-in-tableview

Comment: After I tried code above the problem still occurs https://ibb.co/kxhaKQ If you see the image its load only 3 three picture and others still be placeholder image(human icon) Do I have to reloadData somewhere?

Comment: I found a weird problem if I replace file name into like this appendingPathComponent("myimage.png") the image show correctly without any problem but if I change to file name from CoreData fetched result like appendingPathComponent(result.imageName) and if let image    = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path) always return false

It seems a problem of Coredata not finished load yet?